# How do I create a playfab leaderboard and send player stats to it using to their playfab ID?

Tags: authentication, unity-game-engine, game-development, leaderboard, playfab

I am not sure how to create a Playfab leaderboard and add scores to a user, based on their Playfab ID retrieved from the details they've entered in my 2 player login system. Both players enter their details (email, password) separately.

My 2 player login system for the game is fully functional and I have worked out how to retrieve their unique Playfab IDs. I have stored both playfab IDs as strings I don't know how to use them to update a specific player's stats.